# How do I manage AWS SNS and FCM push notifications when a user is automatically logged out and logs in with a different ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I have an app that can receive push notifications using the AWS SNS-FCM config. I am facing somewhat of a session management issue related to the push notifications.

When a user doesn't use the app for a long time, their cognito tokens expire and they are basically logged out of account A. I still continue sending push notifications and this behavior is what I expect.

The problem is when the user opens the app after a long time and logs in with a **different** id B, they end up receiving notifications for both the accounts A and B as the FCM token hasn't expired and SNS continues to use it as a target.

As in the above scenario, the account A automatically logged out, I don't see a trigger for me to do some cleanup and make sure the endpoint/token is removed from DB/SNS.

How should something like this be handled ?

I have created an API that can be hit when the user deliberately logs out . This will clean up the user and device mappings from the DB and SNS but it will not be hit in the case of token expiration